# How to Re-route to the correct destination if the request url is not correct

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a little question about fix routing .if the requested url is not correct ?

In my RouteConfig i have this method :

```
routes.MapRoute(
         "Book",
         "Book/{id}/{UrlSlug}",
         new { controller = "Book", action = "Book" }
        );
```

But if actually if the url id is correct and the urlsluf is anything else it show the right book, and i don't like this to be honest ,and here is example of my route :

```
localhost/book/12/asp-mvc-2016 =>Right urlslug & show the book info
localhost/book/12/a =>incorrect urlslug & show book info
```

I want to redirect or fix the routing to the real and true urlslug i have in db .

Also here is my controller method looks :

```
 public ActionResult Book(int? id, string UrlSlug)
    {}
```

how i can do that ?

Comment: didn't understand your question. What issue are you getting and what would you like to have?

Comment: Then your method needs to look up the database based on the ID and return the slug. If it does not match the value of the `UrlSlug` parameter, then redirect back to itself.

Comment: @StephenMuecke is quite right. Actually, you should not depend on slug to retrieve info from db. You should use id for that. You can check Stackoverflow question url too which don't rely on slug, instead it uses id.